# Email service/plugin for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for an email service or plugin for ASP.NET that will allow me to send daily email updates to my email list based on information i have stored in a database.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Castle EmailSender Component](http://www.castleproject.org/components/emailsender/index.html) to send emails.

[Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net) for scheduling the daily task.
(Or write your own scheduling, [nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-build-a-task-scheduler-system-for-the-asp-net-ndash-part-1/](http://nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-build-a-task-scheduler-system-for-the-asp-net-ndash-part-1/) )

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any 'plugin' that you can use, but the .Net framework has the System.Net.Mail classes.

For more information, see here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

and here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210616111943/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy to send email from system.net.mail classes. see the my blog link..
http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2009/07/sending-email-through.html.

For sending email periodically you can create a web service and web service will be periodically called by java script based of time offset set by you in windows.SetTimeout

There are another interesting link for java script and web service like following: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210616115431/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101707-1.aspx
http://vishalbansod.wordpress.com/2007/01/06/calling-a-javascript-function-with-parameter-periodically/
http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp/Ajax_WebService/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple task since .NET already provides very nice API for sending email inside the System.Net.Mail namespace. Dont realize too much on a third party tool. Create a simple windows sceduler that runs everyday.